# How to integrate android aar in xamarin project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin application,i want to integrate native android aar in xamarin project.I tried by converting android aar into dll to xamarin project but i am getting so many errors while building.In my android aar so many third party libraries(dagger,rxjava) are there.Is there any way to fix these errors in this project

we are using Android AIDL

sample does not implement inherited abstract member ‘Callable.sData(HttpURLConnection)' (CS0534) (AarBinding)

Error CS0534: ‘Callback' does not implement inherited abstract member '(CS0534) (AarBinding)
 Error CS0115: ‘apiRequestContents()': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (AarBinding)

Comment: "Is there any way to fix these errors" - what errors?  You haven't included any meaningful detail about what the errors are, or even what process you used to "converting android aar into dll".

Comment: errors are added

Comment: is xamarin supports android aidl

Answer (score 0):

> How to integrate android aar in xamarin project

You could refer to: [Binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/), this walkthrough provides step-by-step instructions for creating a Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library from an Android `.aar` file.

If there is some error when you using the binding library, you could refer to the following link:

- [Approaching a Xamarin.Android Bindings Case](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb).
- [Customizing Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/)
- [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/)

> is xamarin supports android aidl

The answer is Yes. To use them add `aidl` files into your project and set `Build Action` to `AndroidInterfaceDefinition`. `Xamarin.Android` will generate `.cs` files, that are compiled together with your source code, so you can use aidl interfaces in your `C#` code.

Here is the official [demo](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/AIDLDemo/AIDLDemo) about how to use `AIDL` in `Xamarin.Android`.